# sound and noise from across a wall dividing two rooms

Tags: grammar

What is the word used to describe the disturbing sound/noise heard through a dividing wall when a couple are engaging in sexual intercourse?

Comment: It depends on how specific you’d like to be about the sounds. There are many words that make it clear the speaker is disturbed by the sound (such as “racket”), there are many words for the many sounds that might accompany sexual intercourse, and there are many ways to indicate the origin of the sound and/or the associated transformation of the sound by virtue of its travel through a wall. To my knowledge, there is no single word that captures all of this at once.

Comment: Please write more about _what_ exactly you wish to express, and _why_ (situation, intention, etc.).

Comment: Certain errors (like “hear” in your question and the second “was” in your comment below) motivate me to inform you of [our sister site, ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), a community specifically centered on learning English. You may find it useful as a repository of specifically focused knowledge or as the ideal forum for future inquiries such as may not be a good fit here among questions of linguistics, etymology, and other arcana.

Comment: You could use a euphemism (be creative) or just call them "sex noises". A lot depends on whether you're writing a complaint to the building manager or writing erotica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could describe it, depending on context. You might say they are *disturbing the peace*, being *raucous*, or just *noisy*. If you want to be subtle, you could just applaud them the next time you see them. When they ask why you're clapping you can explain that you enjoyed their performance.

Comment: Thanks. Raucous was the word used to describe the situation in a rather modest manner, when asked to expatiate the reporter went further to describe was actually happened.

Comment: @user91994 The above comment makes very little sense to me, but I’m glad you feel you were helped here. Please feel free to expand on your question anyway for posterity.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a single term for that has been coined to describe that specific phenomenon, you’re welcome to co-opt the acronym **“L.A.P.”**, which I found on Urban Dictionary:

> ### L.A.P.
>
> Live Audio Porn.
>
> One is treated to L.A.P. when a neighbor/roommate with whom you share a thin wall, or live close enough to, has loud sex. Generally characterized as a truly terrifying experience in which the recipient of the L.A.P. is subjected to aural terrorism in the form of moans, groans, yelps, heavy breathing, bed/furniture crashing, and various other unsettling noises.
>
> *Last night, while I was trying to study for my final, my disgusting roommate and his girlfriend treated me to L.A.P.*
> <sub>Source: [Urban Dictionary definition for “L.A.P.”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lap&defid=2402487)</sub>

If you want anyone to understand what you’re referring to without further explanation, you’re better off describing it in other words. Personally, I’d form a suitably descriptive statement around the term **“sex noises”** which is commonly used/understood in my experience.

Comment: I like it! L.A.P which also spells lap, which many associate with lap dancing. Perfect! Would be helpful to know just *how well-known* this expression is.